# RxJava observable: Invoke onError and then retry

Tags: rx-java

I'm currently using `retry()` to re-subscribe to my `Observable` if an error occurs. 
In this way my `Subscriber`'s `onError` is not called: there is a way to let `onError` be called and THEN re-subscribe to the `Observable`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) If you invoke onError then your observable will not emit any more items. For this reason alone I do not think that you should try implement it this way(allowing the error to propagate to the subscriber).

If you want to execute any action upon an error then try to use [`doOnError()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) before [`retry()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html).

So your code could look like this:

```
getObservableThatMaybeEmitsTheError()
    .doOnError(throwable -> LogTheErrorMethod(throwable))
    .retry()
    ...
    .subscribe()
```